# How to deploy to docker-registry via Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, docker, containers

I have a webapi project created in Visual Studio 2017. Also I have Dockerfile and docker-compose file for building final image.
It is required to deploy this image to remote linux-host with docker installed. I have url and credentials for connection via ssh.
I tried to create publish profile using Custom Container Registry template, which requires Registry URL and credentials for it. I have putted url and credentials which I have.
After I press Publish image build process starts and image builds successfuly. But stage of deploying ends with error: `WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.Error response from daemon: Get https://zzz.net:443/v2/: dial tcp x.x.x.x:443: connect: connection refused"`

Sorry, I am new in Docker and maybe I did something wrong.
I hope there are cosy ways to deploy with Visual Studio tools